# image drag and display

Tags: php, jquery, forms

How image drag and display corresponding row and how take that image's name when sumit form we have four images on topof the page.each images have each value.then below that display some words row by row.whenever we drga tha image from the top to the corresponding words,then we can identify that image name,corresponding words when submitting the form.

my jquery code is here

```
<SCRIPT>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#move").draggable();
 });
 </SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#move1").draggable();
 });
 </SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#move2").draggable();
 });
 </SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#move3").draggable();
 });
 </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: This question is completely meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

"image drag and display" indicates user interaction.  This can't be done in PHP.  Interaction like this needs to be done client-side which means javascript.

PHP is completely server-side.

EDIT:  When I wrote the answer there was no mention of javascript or jQuery so I was pointing out that php couldn't do what he was asking since it's only tagged php (I'm about to edit that).

A better answer would be that the image would need to be a part of the form, otherwise it won't be submitted to php.

Comment: Well, he's using jquery apparently... thing is, the question is far from being clear...